# How to replace two tags with php and regular expression into one

Tags: php, regex

I need help if you can help me. I need regular expression pattern to replace this:

```
</table> <br /> 
or this (without space in between)
</table><br />

(it can be <br /> or <br>)
```

with only table close tag, to remove br tag at the end.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please read up on [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question, it will get you alot further..

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<\/table>|<br \/>|<br>`

check here [Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: That will find all closing tables and line breaks. I think OP only wants closing tables with a trailing line break.